# Renaming each element in a list using select.list

Tags: r, rename, apply

I would like to rename a list of abbreviated names with their full name. It would be easiest if I could pull up a GUI list to choose from for each name.

So given a list of unique abbreviated names

```
 Abbrev<-c("C","Ca","CA","D","Do","Ham","Hammy","C","Hammy","D","Ham")
 Abbrev<-unique(Abbrev)
```

And a list of their full names

```
 Full<-c('Cat','Dog','Hamster')
```

Ideally I would like to go through each element in the Abbrev list, and have it pop up on my screen along with a list of Full names to choose from. So for each unique abbreviation I would like to pull a

```
select.list(Full)
```

The end result would look like this:

```
Abbrev   Full
 C        Cat
 Ca       Cat
 CA       Cat
 D        Dog
 Do       Dog
 Ham      Hamster
 Hammy    Hamster
```

I realize I could set each abbreviation equal to it's full name (DF$Abbrev=="C"<- "Cat") to create this list, but I am hoping to set each individual row based on the "Full" name list

Comment: `sapply(Abbrev, function(x) select.list(Full))` (hit choices 1,1,1,2,2,3,3)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually want to use a GUI interface to do this, try something like this:

```
out <- lapply(Abbrev,function(x) {
    z <- select.list(Full,title=paste("Name:",x))
    return(list(abbrev=x,full=z))
})
out <- cbind(sapply(out,function(x) x$abbrev), sapply(out,function(x) x$full))
fullout <- out[out[,1]==Abbrev,2]
```

But, @RicardoSaporta is right that this seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, `pmatch` can do a lot of the lifting for you:

```
# using pmatch does much of the work for you: 
someNames <- Full[sapply(tolower(Abbrev), pmatch, tolower(Full))]
names(Abbrev) <- someNames
Abbrev
#    Cat     Cat     Cat     Dog     Dog Hamster    <NA>     Cat    <NA>     Dog  Hamster 
#    "C"    "Ca"    "CA"     "D"    "Do"   "Ham" "Hammy"     "C" "Hammy"     "D"    "Ham"
```

The ones that did not match can be found via `is.na`

```
is.na(Abbrev)

# or modified by hand: 
names(Abbrev)[c(7, 9)] <- c("Hamster", "Hamster") 

Abbrev
```